C#/OpenXML Excel Add Image
I'm trying to add a Logo into an Excel Spreadsheet using OpenXML. Here's some demo/debugging the code i have come up with:
Update: Here's a demo repository: https://github.com/LeeStevens318/so-79064374. Instead of the LINQPad Code
void Main()
{
    // Template File
    var templatePath = "C:\\Users\\Lee Stevens\\Downloads\\DEMO\\Blank.xlsx";
    var templateSheetName = "Sheet1";
    
    // Output File
    var destinationPath = "C:\\Users\\Lee Stevens\\Downloads\\DEMO\\File.xlsx";
    
    // Image to Add
    var image = new ExcelSheetImage
    {
        Name = "Logo",
        ImagePath = "C:\\Users\\Lee Stevens\\Downloads\\DEMO\\image1.png",
        Column = 1,
        Row = 1,
        Width = 100,
        Height = 100
    };

    AddImageToCell(templatePath, destinationPath, image, templateSheetName);
}

public void AddImageToCell(string templatePath, string filePath, ExcelSheetImage image, string worksheetName)
{
    File.Copy(templatePath, filePath, overwrite: true);

    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
        Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == worksheetName);

        if (sheet == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Worksheet not found.");

        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);

        DrawingsPart drawingsPart;
        if (worksheetPart.DrawingsPart == null)
        {
            drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new Drawing { Id = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) });
        }
        else
        {
            drawingsPart = worksheetPart.DrawingsPart;
        }

        ImagePart imagePart = drawingsPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(image.ImagePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }

        if (drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing == null)
            drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new WorksheetDrawing();

        WorksheetDrawing worksheetDrawing = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing;

        NonVisualDrawingProperties nonVisualProperties = new NonVisualDrawingProperties
        {
            Id = new UInt32Value((uint)(worksheetDrawing.ChildElements.Count + 1)),
            Name = image.Name
        };

        BlipFill blipFill = new BlipFill(
            new Blip { Embed = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), CompressionState = BlipCompressionValues.Print },
            new Stretch(new FillRectangle())
        );

        Transform2D transform = new Transform2D(
            new Offset { X = 0, Y = 0 },
            new Extents { Cx = image.Width * 9525, Cy = image.Height * 9525 } // Width & Height in EMUs (1 pixel = 9525 EMUs)
        );

        ShapeProperties shapeProperties = new ShapeProperties(transform,
            new PresetGeometry(new AdjustValueList()) { Preset = ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle });

        TwoCellAnchor twoCellAnchor = new TwoCellAnchor(
            new FromMarker(
                new ColumnId((image.Column - 1).ToString()),
                new ColumnOffset("0"),
                new RowId((image.Row - 1).ToString()),
                new RowOffset("0")
            ),
            new ToMarker(
                new ColumnId(image.Column.ToString()), // Adjust if spanning multiple cells
                new ColumnOffset("0"),
                new RowId(image.Row.ToString()), // Adjust if spanning multiple rows
                new RowOffset("0")
            ),
            new Picture(
                nonVisualProperties,
                new NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties(new PictureLocks { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                blipFill,
                shapeProperties
            ),
            new ClientData()
        );

        worksheetDrawing.Append(twoCellAnchor);
        worksheetDrawing.Save(drawingsPart);
    }
    
     Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(filePath) { UseShellExecute = true });
}

public class ExcelSheetImage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}

The code half works. It's adding the Image to the destination file (if you convert to zip and have a look inside it's there), but when opening the document i get: We've found a problem with some context in 'File.xlsx' Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?. I click yes, i still get a blank sheet, with prompt Repaired Records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part (Drawing shape)
If i remove the line worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new Drawing { Id = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) }); the document opens fine but i still have no Image in the cell.
I have seen and looked at: C# & OpenXML: Insert an image into an excel document but this hasn't helped me fix the issue.
